# Highcharts add symbol on tooltip when over 100 or 1000

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am trying to make the tooltip when it is 100 + and 1000 + Have a symbol after it on the toolbar but also have it so that shared: true. Also on the graph when it is say 2394 I am after it to round it down to 2.39 so the graph is not so large and then on the tool bar it would show 2.39K.

I have tried quite a bit and I am not able to figure this out look all over stack overflow and not found anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/sb7n32zn/22/

This is what i currently have:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.2f}</b><br/>',

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a tooltip.formatter which and detect values > 1000. Then use [Highcharts.numberFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.numberFormat) and convert number.

```
formatter: function() {
    var points = this.points,
      each = Highcharts.each,
      txt = '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + points[0].key + '</span><br/>',
      H = Highcharts,
      value,
      numericSymbolDetector;

    each(points, function(point, i) {
      value = point.y;
      numericSymbolDetector = Math.abs(point.y);
      if (numericSymbolDetector > 1000) {
         value = H.numberFormat(value / 1000, 2, '.','' ) + 'k';
      } 
      txt += '<span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name + ': <b>' + value + '</b><br/>';
    });

    return txt;
  }
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/k8783k80/

Comment: Thanks for this. But I am wondering how you can make it so that on the graph it also goes down to 2.8 for 2.8k So that it will show the rest of the graph more equally.

Comment: Do you mean that on yAxis shoud be 2.8k istead of 2.5k ?

Comment: I mean when its 2800 how can i make the graph show it in 2.8 instead but on tooltip show 2.8k

Comment: You can use yAxis.labels.formatter and return this.value. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kzL0phfu/

Comment: Hi, Y i tried that but the graph does not resize, it makes the graph not visible and it should show like this https://gyazo.com/6cbbd668c9ace1da08df13dd4b7ae2ab

But I can get it to work like that with out setting data: [3.843, 7, 7, 6, 15.7, 11.78, 22.05] but it needs to be like this data: [3843, 7, 7, 6, 15.7, 11.78, 22.05] but show the same as in the img of the graph i sent. This is the problem I have been having.

Comment: I am very very thankful for your help and how much you have helped me already